# Modify certain cells depending on given conditions using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

assume I have a dataframe looks like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
              'name' : ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'],
              'john_01' : [1, 2, 3],
              'mary_02' : [4,5,6],
              'peter_03' : [7, 8, 9],
              'roger_04' : [10,11, 12],
              'ken_05' : [13, 14, 15],
                 })

df2 = df.set_index('name')

          john_01  ken_05  mary_02  peter_03  roger_04
name                                              
1st         1      13        4         7        10
2nd         2      14        5         8        11
3rd         3      15        6         9        12


Modify_List_col = ['mary_02','peter_03']

Modify_List_row = ['2nd'] # use tolist() to get this list from additional files
```

I only want to modify those cells in List_col and List_row. So I will get something like below, those cells are replaced by 'X'.

```
      john_01  ken_05  mary_02  peter_03  roger_04
name                                              
1st         1      13        4         7        10
2nd         2      14        X         X        11
3rd         3      15        6         9        12
```

Does anyone know how to get the results in one line using pandas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `loc` method:

```
In[25]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)).set_index(0)

In[26]: df
Out[26]: 
     1   2   3   4
0                 
0    1   2   3   4
5    6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24


In[27]: df.loc[[10,15],[2,3,4]] = "x"

In[28]: df
Out[28]: 
     1   2   3   4
0                 
0    1   2   3   4
5    6   7   8   9
10  11   x   x   x
15  16   x   x   x
20  21  22  23  24
```

To do that, just set the column 0 as index, then select the portion of the dataframe with `loc` and assign the value "x".

It works in the same way for your last dataset:

```
In[51]: Modify_List_col = ['mary_02', 'peter_03']
        Modify_List_row = ['2nd']
        df.loc[Modify_List_row, Modify_List_col] = "X"

In[52]: df
Out[52]: 
      john_01  ken_05 mary_02 peter_03  roger_04
name                                            
1st         1      13       4        7        10
2nd         2      14       X        X        11
3rd         3      15       6        9        12
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to give the columns and rows as a list respectively to do so. I have thousands of cols and rows to be modified. They are indeed string. Do you know how?

Comment: you can also use `df.loc[Modify_List_row,Modify_List_col]` (the list values must be integers because so it's created by default)

Comment: Thanks, but as my column name and row name are string. I will get the name from other files to make a list. So I may wait for guys to give suggestion!

Comment: well, you have two options, change the indexes to `str` or your lists to `int`

Comment: I have edited the post to show you the second option that i comment.

Comment: Thanks, but how about if my row and col name is `['john', 'mary', 'peter']` rather than a number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111474/discussion-between-ej-f-and-sakura).