# Copying pandas dataframe slice into another slice of the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to expand on this post (except I'm using Python 3):
[Modify certain cells depending on given conditions using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122321/modify-certain-cells-depending-on-given-conditions-using-pandas?rq=3)

There you have a pandas data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
              'name' : ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'],
              'john_01' : [1, 2, 3],
              'mary_02' : [4,5,6],
              'peter_03' : [7, 8, 9],
              'roger_04' : [10,11, 12],
              'ken_05' : [13, 14, 15],
                 })

df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
```

which gives

```
          john_01  ken_05  mary_02  peter_03  roger_04
name                                              
1st         1      13        4         7        10
2nd         2      14        5         8        11
3rd         3      15        6         9        12
```

...and the OP wanted to set two cells under 'mary_02' and 'peter_03' in row '2nd" to a fixed value 'X'. The preferred solution was

```
Modify_List_col = ['mary_02', 'peter_03']
Modify_List_row = ['2nd']
df.loc[Modify_List_row, Modify_List_col] = "X"
```

...and that works.

(P.S. my df contains heterogeneous data and is *not* strictly numeric, and although the example only selects a single row, my use case selects several, but source row and dest row lists are disjoint - no common rows.)

I want to copy a same-shaped portion from another part of the same dataframe, say `df.loc(['john_01', 'ken_05'],['3rd'])` into the same locations as above. This operation seems to be remarkably rare, and I have a hard time finding any example to guide.

For example:

```
src_cols  = ['john_01','ken_05']
src_rows  = ['3rd']
df.loc[src_rows,src_cols]
```

```
john_01 ken_05
name        
3rd 3   15
```

...but

```
dest_cols = ['mary_02', 'peter_03']
dest_rows = ['2nd']

df.loc[dest_rows, dest_cols] = df.loc[src_rows,src_cols]
df
```

yields

```
        john_01 ken_05  mary_02 peter_03 roger_04
name                    
1st 1.0 13.0    4.0 7.0 10.0
2nd 2.0 14.0    NaN NaN 11.0
3rd 3.0 15.0    6.0 9.0 12.0
```

...whereas dropping (shamefaced) to loops works:

```
for srow, drow in zip(src_rows,dest_rows):
    for scol,dcol in zip(src_cols,dest_cols):
        df.loc[drow,dcol] = df.loc[srow,scol]
df
```

```
    john_01 ken_05  mary_02 peter_03 roger_04
name                    
1st 1.0 13.0    4.0 7.0 10.0
2nd 2.0 14.0    3.0 15.0    11.0
3rd 3.0 15.0    6.0 9.0 12.0
```

I also tried looping just the rows, but got the same incorrect result.

Can someone please explain why, and how else to avoid loops?

Edit: if it helps, think of doing a simple copy/paste operation of a few cells in a row of an Excel spreadsheet to another row, say G3:G7 to D10:D14. That's what I'm trying to do. And the cells can contain anything.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself :

> "..but source <s>row</s> index and dest <s>row</s> index lists are
> disjoint - **no common <s>rows</s> indexes.**"

That's why you're getting `NaN`*s* because pandas fails to align the indexes when you assign the slices of DataFrames returned by [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). You need to use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to bypass the *index-alignement* :

```
src_cols  = ['john_01','ken_05']
src_rows  = ['3rd'] # `src_idx` would be more accurate
​
dest_cols = ['mary_02', 'peter_03']
dest_rows = ['2nd'] # `dest_idx` would be more accurate
​
df.loc[dest_rows, dest_cols] = df.loc[src_rows, src_cols].to_numpy()​
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
      john_01  mary_02  peter_03  roger_04  ken_05
name                                              
1st         1        4         7        10      13
2nd         2        3        15        11      14
3rd         3        6         9        12      15
```

Comment: **NB**: `src_cols` and `dest_cols` must have the same length. Otherwise, you'll get a *shape-mismatch*.

Comment: When I said no common rows (not indices), I was referring to my actual problem, not the toy problem in the post, where I'm just copying one slice to a different location.

So there's something about "index alignment" that I fundamentally don't understand. I've specified precisely what rows/cols need to be altered and the precise rows/cols with the content. So I don't get what this alignment is that it's trying to do...

Finally, I think I mentioned that my actual use case contains heterogeneous data, so "to_numpy" is not an option; it won't handle non-numeric data, last I tried anyway...

Comment: Are you saying that the source slice has to be extracted completely so that it's not a dataframe any more, it's something else that is unmoored from dataframe indexing? Is there a way to do that without using to_numpy, since not all the data is numeric (although in the toy, it is; think for instance that another column exists with booleans, or a string)